# C# Закрытие окна

Tags: c#

Извиняюсь за такой тупой вопрос, но я просто разбит, что не могу понять.
Программа работает так, сначала запускается форма с логотипом, а потом через некоторое время (timer) он открывает второе окно. Но он так должен работать, а по факту 1-ое окно вообще никак не хочет закрываться...

Использовал код и такой:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//интервал(1000 = 1 сек)
            timer1.Interval = 4000;
            //запускаем таймер
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
       Form ifs = new Form1(); //в form_load пишем
    Form ifrm = new Form2();
    ifrm.Show(); 
        ifs.Close(); // или ifs.hide();
}
```

Этот код мне ничего не дал (что на 1-ом окне, что на 2-ом)

Так же пытался через такой код:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        string nameP = "Form1";
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] AllProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
      foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process Optimised in AllProc)
       if (Optimised.ProcessName.Contains(nameP))
        {Optimised.Kill();}
    }
```

В чём моя ошибка? почему не закрывается?

Comment: в каком месте вы этот код пишите? Program.cs или где? дайте больше вводных

Comment: в Form1.cs или Form2.cs в event -> Form_load(); (так больше нету данных, это всё... я в коментах к коду указал, сейчас исправлю пост

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак. У вас есть 2 формы, на `Form1` у вас присутствует `Timer`
В методе `Form1_Load` вы, допустим, задаете интервал и запускаете `Timer`
Дальше все действия с Show/Hide форм должны происходить в методе `timer1_Tick`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 5 * 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        // показываем Form2
        form2.Show();
        // прячем Form1
        this.Hide();
        // останавливаем таймер
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Заработало! Но я так и не врубился в чём мой косяк был? это потому, что я использовал `timer1.Enabled = true//false;` в замен `timer1.start()` ?

Comment: Ошибка скорее в том, что вы создавали новый экземпляр класса `Form1` `Form ifs = new Form1();`